# Angular 2 subscription not working

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having the following issue with Angular 2 at the moment.

My service is working correctly, I've added `console.log()` to my service to check that it's pulling through, which it is. My service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  location: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getCurrentLocation(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.get('service-method-here')
   .map((result: Response) => result.json())
     .map((data: any) => {
       let location: string = '';
       if(data) {
         console.log(data.description);
         location = data.description;
       }
       return this.location;
      });
  }
}
```

Inside my component however, I'm calling the service like so. It is invoking my service as the `console.log()s` I had placed inside the method are being displayed in the console correctly. This is how I'm calling the service inside my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '...';
import { Service } from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ...,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, Component]
})
  export class Component implements OnInit {
  public locationName: string;
  constructor(public service: Service) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCurrentLocation()
      .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.locationName = data
            },
            error => {
              console.log('error');
            });
}
```

The `console.log()` inside the component is returning `undefined`. The HTML on my page for completeness sake looks like so:

```
<h4>{{locationName}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your service this line

```
location = data.description;
```

should be

```
this.location = data.description;
```

otherwise a different location is returned than the one that was set

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  location: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getCurrentLocation(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.get('service-method-here')
   .map((result: Response) => result.json())
     .map((data: any) => {
       let location: string = '';
       if(data) {
         console.log(data.description);
         this.location = data.description; // <== 
       }
       return this.location;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two locations 1) local `let location...` 2) and components `this.location`

```
.map((data: any) => {
   //let location: string = '';
   if(data) {
     console.log(data.description);
     // we should assign the components property, not the 
     // local variable
     //location = data.description;
     this.location = data.description;
   }
   // this is returned
   return this.location;
  });
```

And because the components is not init at all

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
public locationName: string;
...
```

we get undefined

Comment: Enjoy Angular2 and observable anyway ;)